# Is tf.random.normal cryptographically secure?

Tags: tensorflow, random, cryptography

I'd like to sample from a normal distribution using a cryptographically secure library, and then add the result to a TensorFlow tensor. I've heard that python's built-in `random` library is not an option.

Is `tf.random.normal` cryptographically secure? If it isn't, know of anything that'll work?

Comment: I'm intrigued as to why you'd want to do this!  i.e. I presume you're using tensorflow for machine learning/stats, so what does using an (otherwise unspecified) CSPRNG give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  They and other methods in `tf.random` use the Philox and ThreeFry algorithms, and although they are based on cryptographic algorithms, they make no claim to cryptographic security.  As the paper introducing these algorithms says:

> *Any* modification of a cryptographic block cipher would make it unsuitable for its intended use in security, but it is reasonable for PRNG design to trade cryptographic strength for speed while still maintaining [statistical quality].

(Salmon et al., "Parallel Random Numbers: As Easy as 1, 2, 3", 2011.)

Comment: Gotcha, thank you! Do you know of anything that would work?

Comment: No, I don't know of any.

Comment: [`random.SystemRandom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) uses `urandom` which is specified to be [suitable for cryptographic use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom)

Comment: @SamMason: This question is about TensorFlow's `tf.random`, not Python's `random` module.

Comment: I interpret the question as asking for clarification about whether "python's built-in `random` library" can generate Gaussian samples from a CSPRNG (it can, under most Unixes and Windows anyway) and whether the resulting values can be used in tensorflow (they can, after converting to a `Tensor`).  Hence this seems like something that could work.

Comment: @SamMason: The question is "Is tf.random.normal cryptographically secure?".  And the direct answer to that question is "No".  The question, as written in its title, has nothing to do with any other random number generator, including Python's `random` module.  In any case, if you have more insights that may answer this question, post them in their own answer.

Answer (score 2):

As Peter states `tensorflow.random.normal` is not a CSPRNG.  I'll therefore answer your "Do you know of anything that would work?" question, rather than the question in the title that's been in the negative.

Python's `random` module can provide access to your operating system's CSPRNG, e.g. [`getrandom(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) under Linux and *BSD.  This happens via the [`SystemRandom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) class which in turn uses the [`os.urandom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) call to get access to the host's `getrandom` syscall (or [`CryptGenRandom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom) under Windows).

To get a Gaussian variate from this into `tensorflow` you would do something like:

```
import random
import tensorflow as tf

rng = random.SystemRandom()

tf.convert_to_tensor([rng.gauss(0, 1) for _ in range(10)])
```

which gives you a `Tensor` of shape `(10,)`.